# How to store text in JSON object and output to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the following code working in a JSFiddle(http://jsfiddle.net/mattography/E4aqW/), but can't figure out how to get the article under the "Photography" heading stored in a JSON object and output to a div, similar to how I have the menu setup.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-4">
        <ul id="menu"></ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">
         <h1>Photography</h1> This is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-4">
         <h3>Related Articles</h3>

        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Nature Photography</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Tilt Shift Technique</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Night Time Photography</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div id='normalDialog'>
            <input type="button" value="Login">
            <!-- Modal Dialog Div -->
            <div id="dialog-confirm"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
ul li {
list-style-type: square;
text-decoration:none;
}
#menu {
position: relative;
top: 30px;
}
.ui-menu {
width: 150px;
z-index: 1000;
}
```

JQUERY

```
$(function () {

var data = {
    menu: [{
        name: 'Cost',
        link: '0',
        sub: [{
            name: 'Digital',
            link: '0-0',
            sub: null
        }, {
            name: 'Film',
            link: '0-1',
            sub: null
        }, {
            name: 'Processing',
            link: '0-2',
            sub: null
        }]
    }, {
        name: 'Digital',
        link: '1',
        sub: [{
            name: 'Cameras',
            link: '1-0',
            sub: null
        }, {
            name: 'Memory',
            link: '1-1',
            sub: null
        }, {
            name: 'HDR',
            link: '1-2',
            sub: null
        }]
    }, {
        name: 'Film',
        link: '2',
        sub: [{
            name: 'Types',
            link: '2-0',
            sub: null
        }, {
            name: 'Processing',
            link: '2-1',
            sub: null
        }, {
            name: 'ISO',
            link: '2-2',
            sub: null
        }]
    }, {
        name: 'Filters',
        link: '3',
        sub: [{
            name: 'Infrared',
            link: '3-0',
            sub: null
        }, {
            name: 'UV',
            link: '3-1',
            sub: null
        }, {
            name: 'Digital',
            link: '3-2',
            sub: null
        }]
    }, {
        name: 'Process',
        link: '4',
        sub: [{
            name: 'Digital',
            link: '4-1',
            sub: null
        }, {
            name: 'Film',
            link: '4-2',
            sub: null
        }, {
            name: 'History',
            link: '4-3',
            sub: null
        }]
    }]
};
var getMenuItem = function (itemData) {
    var item = $("<li>")
        .append(
    $("<a>", {
        href: '#' + itemData.link,
        html: itemData.name
    }));
    if (itemData.sub) {
        var subList = $("<ul>");
        $.each(itemData.sub, function () {
            subList.append(getMenuItem(this));
        });
        item.append(subList);
    }
    return item;
};

var $menu = $("#menu");
$.each(data.menu, function () {
    $menu.append(
    getMenuItem(this));
});
$menu.menu();
});


function fnOpenNormalDialog() {
var buf = "Username: " + "<input type='textbox'>" + "<br /><br />" +
    "Password: " + "<input type='password'>";

// buf will be shown on the body of Dialog.
$("#dialog-confirm").html(buf);

// Define the Dialog and its properties.
$("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
    resizable: false,
    modal: true,
    title: "Login",
    height: 250,
    width: 400,
    buttons: {
        "Login": function () {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        },
            "Cancel": function () {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    }
});
}
// Define the click events of the divs.
$('#normalDialog').click(fnOpenNormalDialog);
```

Comment: I don't get the question ...

Comment: I don't see a JS object with a Photography article. If you would like to replace the lorem ipsum text, then you should wrap it with another element (like `div`) and replace the text like `$("#my-div").html(article_text)`. If I'm not understanding your intentions, please clarify.

Comment: @unclekyky I think he wants us to insert text using a JSON object like he did with the menu. Perhaps add an `mainArticle` object property to `data` and use that.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a `mainArticle` object attribute to `data` with a `heading` and an `article` attribute. Then, append the heading and article attribute into the element you want to put the article. Remember to put the heading in a `<h1>` tag.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/E4aqW/1/

```
var data = {
    [...]
    //Main Article Info
    mainArticle: {
        heading: "Photography",
        article: "This is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum."
    }
};

[...]

//Main Article DOM Manipulation
$("#mainArticle").append( $("<h1>").html(data.mainArticle.heading) ).append( data.mainArticle.article );
```